# URL translations transposing between primary and secondary languages or just displaying wrong

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

We have a Drupal 8.7.10 site, multilingual (17 countries localized with 2 or more languages each).

In the example I am attaching, we have a "people" page where we are listing people for our company in this country. The URL path should show "insalar" instead of "people" for the Turkey Turkish translation. The form field for the path shows correctly. But the "View" tab, as well as the listing in the admin list, shows "people". (pictured below)

The English page links are showing "insalar". So it is inverting it for some reason. But it doesn't happen for all content types and it doesn't even happen all the time. Nor does it seem to happen for every translation (and we have A LOT).

Any idea what might be happening?

[image]

Comment: Alias pattern are config entities with langcode, could be that your configurations are swapping their langcode? We us to get some troubles like so when editing configurations their langcoded was set to the UI language.

Comment: I already checked that and the configuration for the patterns shows the correct string for the language and the site default. Now I will say that we have "Turkey (Turkish)" defined in the patterns but not "Turkey (English)" instead relying on the fallback of the site default for the content type which is "people".

Comment: Also, whoever downvoted this it would be helpful to explain why you think this should be closed. Kinda hard to fix what I don't know about.

Comment: I should point out that the problem will sometimes happen in one node of the people content type, but not another. In the same country and language combo. Very intermittent. Though once the problem happens to a particular node it seems to be persistent to that node.